# MongoDB service not starting on RedHat - missing 'service_uri'

Tags: mongodb, nosql, redhat

I'm on a `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.4 (Tikanga)` machine

I created my `/etc/yum.repos.d/10gen.repo` like this:

```
[10gen]
name=10gen Repository
baseurl=http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

I installed MongoDB with: `sudo yum install mongo-10gen mongo-10gen-server`

but when I run: `sudo service mongod start`

I get: `Missing SERVICE_URI environment variable`

help! :)

Answer (score 1):

That sounds more like a problem with the service command than with MongoDB or the install.  Try starting it from init.d instead:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mongod start
```

Answer (score 0):

The `service` program you have in your PATH is not the one you want to run (it's a proprietary script). Use `/sbin/service` instead of `service`